# Is it possible to lag a variable on multiple dimensions without storing the lagged variables?

Tags: r, dplyr

It's possible to use `lag(x)` directly - without storing it as a variable -  when working with one dimension, but I don't know how to do it when lagging on multiple dimensions. On this example, I store `xc_1` and `xt_1` explicitly before performing the computation.

For example using a dummy data set:

```
dtf <- data_frame(t = rep(2001:2003, 2),
                  c = rep(1:2,each=3),
                  x = rnorm(6))
```

Compute something based on x<sub>t-1</sub> and x<sub>c-1</sub>

```
dtf <- dtf %>%
        # lag over t 
        group_by(c) %>% mutate(xt_1 = lag(x)) %>% 
        # lag over c
        group_by(t) %>% mutate(xc_1 = lag(x)) %>% 
        # place function computation here
        mutate(result = xt_1 * xc_1)
```

Is there a function of the form `lag(x, by=c)` and `lag(x, by=t)` that could be used to perform the computation directly, without intermediate variables?

Comment: No there isn't (as far as I know, but I could be wrong). At least that is what I do when I want to group_by different var each time.